# Is there a way to convert dot notation in bracket notation?

Tags: javascript, vue.js

I am trying to convert the String:

```
string.0.another.0.string
```

into

```
string[0].another[0].string.
```

I have tried using **RegEx**, `split()`, for loops but I am having no success.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: can you elaborate on the question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use regex to match this pattern ".(any number)." and then replace with the captured number group enclosed with "."

```js
const regex = /\.([0-9])\./g;
const str = 'string.0.another.0.string';
const subst = '.[$1].';
const result = str.replace(regex, subst);
console.log('Substitution result: ', result);
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
let a = 'string.0.another.0.string';

let res='';

a.split('.').forEach(val => {
 res += val === '0' ? '[0].' : val;
});

console.log(res);
```

or a simpler solution:

```js
let a = 'string.0.another.0.string';
let res = a.replace(/.0/g, "[0]");
console.log(res);
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming your string is literally "string[0].another[0].string", [string.replace()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/replace) has your back.

```js
let str = "string.0.another.0.string";
console.log(str);
str = str.replace(/.0./g, "[0].");
console.log(str);
```